# AWS Lambda - Execute not supported languages

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless

AWS Lambda allows to execute the code in Java, Go, PowerShell, Node.js, C#, Python, and Ruby so far.

How can I run a not natively supported language in AWS Lambda, such as C, Rust or others?

Comment: Who says [Rust](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/rust-runtime-for-aws-lambda/) isn't supported? Citation needed. [C++](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-the-c-lambda-runtime/) is supported, and by extension, the C++ form of C.

Comment: Rust is not supported nativelly, as well as C.
AWS says that :) Here the FAQ on AWS website https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/faqs/#:~:text=Q%3A%20What%20languages%20does%20AWS,languages%20to%20author%20your%20functions.

Comment: That documentation is out of date. I've seen many cases where using Rust on Lambda has saved a ton of compute time.

Comment: Well, you're talking about custom runtimes not the nativelly supported languages.
But here comes my question, how can I run another language on Lambda? I assume with custom runtimes for some languages like C++ and, apparently, Rust. Is there a list of possibile custom runtimes available? What about C (not C++)?

Comment: That's not really relevant since your "function" can be a container, and a container can have anything you want in it. [Example](https://hevodata.com/learn/rust-lambda/#8). If you can build it into a container, you can run it. The "default" languages are really just running inside an Amazon-built container, nothing more.

Comment: Either build your own runtime or use a docker container, as has been suggested. The latter will be likely easier to do

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Rust is not supported natively, and I do not believe there are any ways around that. Please refer to the FAQ on the AWS website [https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/faqs/#:~:text=Q%3A%20What%20languages%20does%20AWS,languages%20to%20author%20your%20functions](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/faqs/#:%7E:text=Q%3A%20What%20languages%20does%20AWS,languages%20to%20author%20your%20functions).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).